# Undefined variable: filtersForm in yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

```
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */

$this->title = 'My TLC';
?>
<div class="site-index">

    <div class="jumbotron">
        $this->beginWidget ( 'zii.widgets.CPortlet', [
            'title' => '<span class="icon-picture"></span>Incoming Calls',
            'titleCssClass' => '' 
    ] );
    ?>
    <div id="members"
            style="height: 30%; width: 80%; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px;"></div>

    <?php

    $this->render ( 'in', [
            'filtersForm' => $filtersForm,
            'exportScenario' => $exportScenario,
            'date' => $date,
            'model' => $model,
            'inDataProvider' => $inDataProvider 
    ] );

    $this->endWidget ();
    ?>

    </div>
</div>





<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
    <?php
    $this->beginWidget ( 'zii.widgets.CPortlet', [
            'title' => '<span class="icon-picture"></span>Out Going Calls',
            'titleCssClass' => '' 
    ] );
    ?>
    <div id="members"
            style="height: 30%; width: 80%; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px;"></div>

    <?php

    $this->render ( 'out', [
            'filtersForm' => $filtersForm,
            'exportScenario2' => $exportScenario2,
            'date' => $date,
            'model' => $model,
            'outDataProvider' => $outDataProvider 
    ] );

    $this->endWidget ();
    ?>

    </div>
</div>



<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
    <?php
    $this->beginWidget ( 'zii.widgets.CPortlet', [
            'title' => '<span class="icon-picture"></span>Missed Calls',
            'titleCssClass' => '' 
    ] );
    ?>
    <div id="members"
            style="height: 30%; width: 80%; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px;"></div>

    <?php

    $this->render ( 'missed', [
        'filtersForm' => $filtersForm,
        'exportScenario3' => $exportScenario3,
        'date' => $date,
        'model' => $model,
        'missedDataProvider' => $missedDataProvider 
    ] );

    $this->endWidget ();
    ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

migrating data  from yii1.1 to yii 2. so i decided to do everything from scratch in yii2. unfortunately i keep getting error ..Can someone help me with the issue?

> PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException 
>   Undefined variable: filtersForm
>
> PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
>   Undefined variable: filtersForm
>
> 1. in /var/www/html/master/views/site/index.php at line 21
>         12131415161718192021222324252627282930
>      'titleCssClass' => '' 
>      ] );
>      ?>
>
>    render ( 'in', [
>       'filtersForm' => $filtersForm,
>       'exportScenario' => $exportScenario,
>       'date' => $date,
>       'model' => $model,
>       'inDataProvider' => $inDataProvider 
>       ] );
>      
>       $this->endWidget ();
>       ?>
> 2. in /var/www/html/master/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php at line 250 –yii\base\View::renderPhpFile()
> 3. in /var/www/html/master/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php at line 152 – yii\base\View::renderFile()
> 4. in /var/www/html/master/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php at line 384 – yii\base\View::render()
> 5. in /var/www/html/master/controllers/SiteController.php at line 64 – yii\base\Controller::render()
>         58596061626364656667686970
>
>    - Displays homepage.
>        *
>    - @return string
>        */
>        public function actionIndex()
>        {
>        return $this->render('index');
>        }
>
> /**
>   * Login action.
>   *
>   * @return Response|string

Above is what is displayed on the page

Comment: You are not passing this variable to view in your `actionIndex()`.